# this parameter modifier in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm curious about this code snippet:

```
public static class XNAExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Write a Point
    /// </summary>
    public static void Write(this NetOutgoingMessage message, Point value)
    {
        message.Write(value.X);
        message.Write(value.Y);
    }
    // ...
};
```

What does the `this` keyword mean next to the parameter type? I can't seem to find any information about it anywhere, even in the C# specification.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

The syntax means you can call the method as if it was a member of the NetOutgoingMessage class:

```
var msg = new NetOutgoingMessage();
msg.Write(somePoint);
```

This is basically rewritten by the compiler to:

```
var msg = new NetOutgoingMessage();
XNAExtensions.Write(msg, somePoint);
```

It's just nice syntactical sugar.

Answer (score 5):

That is how an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) is defined.

What this essentially means is that, even though this method is contained in an encapsulating static class, when using the type specified (in the extension method parameters labelled `this`) such a method will be automatically exposed such that:

```
var typeInstance = new TypeWithExtensionMethod();
typeInstance.ExtensionMethod(anyParametersRequiredButNotTypeInstance);
```

Is possible, as opposed to:

```
var type = new TypeWithExtensionMethod();
ExtensionMethods.ExtensionMethod(typeInstance, anyOtherParametersRequired);
```

Answer (score 3):

> What does the this keyword mean next to the parameter type?

It means the method is an extension method.

> I can't seem to find any information about it anywhere, even in the C# specification.

The information you seek is in section 10.6.9 of the C# 4 specification.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that `Write` is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to the `NetOutgoingMessage` class.

Answer (score 0):

It means it is an extension method. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's extension method for `NetOutgoingMessage` class.

See here: [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are passing the reference of the variable. If you assign the returned value to new variable - both the new and the passed variable when calling the method will be the same because inside the method you are changing the passed variable.