# Method signature containing "this" as a parameter modifier

Tags: c#, syntax

I was looking up how to do something when I cam upon a bit of example code that had the following format:

```
public static SecureString ConvertToSecureString(this string password)
{
    // stuff
}
```

What does that "this" do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this parameter modifier in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700016/this-parameter-modifier-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes it an extension method, meaning you will be able to do:

```
var secureString = "someString".ConvertToSecureString();
```

It basically adds functionality to any instance of an object of the type that comes after the keyword "this" in there.

You can read more about extension methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension method - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It's an extension method; in this case so that if you have a string varible, you can convert it to a SecureString object by calling what appears to be an instance method

Answer (score 1):

It's an extension method that adds functionality to objects (such as string, int, or custom classes).

see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

it is for methods extensions, the secureString object within the scope of your current solution will have the ConvertToSecureString method added to its methods;

exp

```
SecureString s = new SecureString ("test"); //whatever is the constructor signature

s.ConvertToSecureString (.....);
```

Comment: Surely it's an extension of the string type not the SecureString type.

Comment: you're right, was more focused on the return type than on the Class itself :)